Excel Find Data and Replace Data in another Cell (if data in Column C is Found in A, Replace B Data with D Data)
I have an excel worksheet with 4 columns, 2 columns of old data and 2 columns of new data



(A) PartCode
(B) Old Description
(C) Part Code
(D) New Description




ABC
Old abc description
DEF
New def description


DEF
Old def description
GHI
New ghi description


GHI
Old ghi description
ABC
New abc description



How can i replace the old description in column B with the new description from column D?
The part codes in A and B are in a random order so cannot be sorted and do not match
Basically search column A using the part code from C, if found then replace B with D for the appropriate rows
This is a one off so if theres another way or possible to do it online i'm open to suggestions.
Tried find and replace

is there a 1 to 1 match, as in every partcode in A is in C?

The data in A and C match, however A only contains 3/4 of the data found in C.
C contains an extra 500 rows of data that isnt in A. The order of A and C differs

You can use VLOOKUP:
=VLOOKUP(A2:A4,C2:D4,2,0)


